# How to get back the locator value from a IWebElement and from the By?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I would like to ask some help. Maybe my question is silly a little bit, but after a few searches I don't know the answer. It could be due to that the majority of the searchers in Google would like to know the opposite than I would. :)

I have an IWebElement which was created by the normal way using WebDriver and C#.

```c#
String locator = "someXpathLocator";    
IWebElement elem = webDriver.FindElement(By.xPath(locator));
```

Later, at another part of the test script I would like to use the **locator** value and manipulate it a little bit, but there I will have only the WebElement. Due to the fact it is not possible - or I don't know how - get back the locator value from a WebElement object I have to provide the locator value somehow. It makes the code more difficult.

So, if I have an web element than how is possible to get back the locator value?

Comment: you need to provide the locator value, be it `id` or `classname` or `xpath` or `name` or `csspath`

Comment: If you want to get an attribute value for a locator, you can get it using `string value = By.xPath("somexPathLocator").getAttribute("your tag name").getValue();`

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking, unfortunately is not possible.  The Webdriver team decided to make it a private variable.

However, a solution that I have used is to use the Decorator pattern for the WebElement that stores a reference to the By.  I don't know C#, so I can't help you with an example, sorry.